# How to disable com.facebook.appmanager?

Tags: facebook, android-12, oppo-coloros

I have no facebook account, and I'm not using the facebook app; I can't even find any facebook app any more.
Still Android's log is flooded by messages from `com.facebook.appmanager`:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Caller com.facebook.appmanager needs to hold android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM to set exact alarms.
    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2471)
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2455)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2438)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2380)
    at android.app.IAlarmManager$Stub$Proxy.set(IAlarmManager.java:377)
    at android.app.AlarmManager.setImpl(AlarmManager.java:957)
    at android.app.AlarmManager.setImpl(AlarmManager.java:917)
    at android.app.AlarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.java:1185)
    at com.facebook.analytics2.logger.dl.a(UploadSchedulerNoDelayHack.java:160)
    at com.facebook.analytics2.logger.dl.a(UploadSchedulerNoDelayHack.java:152)
...
```

However I don't find any active app to disable or stop.

How can I get rid of that process?

Comment: Any app that allows FB login can potentially do it.

Comment: OK, so if I cannot disable the process, can I fix the problem (flooding the log with errors) at least?

Comment: Possibly related on XDA: [\[GUIDE\] How to remove Facebook Services and other bloatware WITHOUT Root](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-how-to-remove-facebook-services-and-other-bloatware-without-root.4143489/), [\[REF\]\[REMOVAL\] Facebook bloatware found on many devices + removal script \[ROOT\]](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/ref-removal-facebook-bloatware-found-on-many-devices-removal-script-root.4116533/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to uninstall the app, you could do that via the adb shell, as described [here](https://www.xda-developers.com/uninstall-carrier-oem-bloatware-without-root-access/)

Essentially:

1. connect phone to a computer with adb installed, and check connectivity with `adb devices` in a terminal
2. Once it finds a device, start an adb shell by entering `adb shell`
3. Search package with `pm list packages | grep 'facebook'`
4. Remove: `pm uninstall -k --user 0 <pkg found above>`

hth!